# Monero RPC get_transfer by php monero-integrations

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, mymonero, php

I try to get the transaction by calling get_transfer, but I dont know how to send the $subaddr_indice to get the right answer back

i have:

```
[subaddr_indices] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [major] => 0
                                [minor] => 7
                            )

                    )
```

and if I try to send:

```
 $get_transfers = $walletRPC->get_transfers('in', 0, '[0][7]');
```

I get all the transfers back and not the one I search for, what is wrong?
thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://github.com/monero-integrations/monerophp/blob/master/docs/walletRPC.md#get_transfers):

```
get_transfers
Look up transfers

Parameters:

$input_types <Array> Array of transfer type strings; possible values include 'all', 'in', 'out', 'pending', 'failed', and 'pool' (optional)
$account_index <number> Index of account to look (optional)
$subaddr_indices <String> Comma-separated list of subaddress indices to look up (optional)
$min_height <number> Minimum block height to use when looking up (optional)
$max_height <number> Maximum block height to use when looking up (optional)
```

So it should be:

```
$walletRPC->get_transfers(['in'], 0, "7");
```

to fetch incoming transfers for account index 0, subaddress index 7.

Comment: thank you, but this does not work, it shows all transfers and not only the one I am looking for with [minor] => 7

Comment: You should file a bug report if it's not working as documented. These wrapper libraries like monerophp are a) really not needed as its simple to call the JSON RPC directly and b) they are often poorly maintained.

Comment: can you give me an example how to make the same call by JSON RPC with Curl?

Comment: https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#get_transfers

Comment: @pdevo Would you mind if I ask you to open an issue if you find one? Thanks.